# I can't boot to recovery mode in zenfone2

Tags: recovery-mode

I manage to get into boot loader.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wuixmZ11Kyc

However, after that, if I select recovery mode and click power button it goes to bootloader again.

The problem is I have CWM installed. And then I Install TWRM again. So it seems that I have 2 recovery modes even though I need only one. I wonder how to solve that.

I can finally go to CWM but only if I reinstall CWM and only for 1 time

Comment: Have you verified you have the correct file and tried just reflashing recovery with 'fastboot flash recovery recovery.img' (replace 'recovery.img' with the name of the TWRP or CWM img file)? You cannot have 2 recoveries, one will over-write the other, if you flashed TWRP and it won't work, try going back to CWM. Are you sure you are not doing fastboot flash recovery.img and forgetting the "extra" recovery parameter.?

Comment: let me try. So I can put recovery.img on my computer and do that.

Comment: Yes... How else would you do it? :)

Comment: Strange from fastboot I can do 'fastboot flash recovery recovery.img' but then cannot do adb reboot recovery because adb can't see any device. The device is connected and cwm installer can connect though. If I go to cwm adb see devices but I can't do fastboot flash recovery

Comment: oh fastboot only works on fastboot. Not on cwm.

Comment: Fastboot and ADB are two different and unique tools... ADB is for talking to Android with the operating system booted, fastboot is for talking through the bootloader on a lower level. Try fastboot reboot-bootloader and start recovery. You must reboot after flashing recovery

Comment: Is there a fastboot command that can boot to recovery?

Comment: No, but you should be able to start recovery from the bootloader via hard keys

Comment: I can get into bootloader fastboot. Select recovery and it goes back to fastboot